# How to determine if a LinkedList of segments are a Polygon?

Tags: java, object, filter, linked-list, polygon

I have been trying to solve this for a day, basically I have this **LinkedList polygon** with each Segment having two variables: **startingPoint** and **endingPoint** and I call them with two methods **p1()** and **p2()**.

I'm making a class that determines when a sequence of segments form a polygon (a polygon is a sequence of at least 3 segments which have in common that segment 1 starts where the n-th segment ends with n> 3).

```
private boolean isAClosedArea(LinkedList<Segment> polygon){

    if (polygon.isEmpty()) return false;

    if ((long) polygon.size() < 3) return false;

    if (((long) polygon.size() == 3) &&
            (polygon.getFirst().p1() == polygon.getLast().p2()))
        return true;

    if((long)polygon.size() > 3)
        return polygon.stream()
                      .filter();

}
```

'
I thought the cleanest way could be a filter on a stream but i have no idea how to do it, can you help me in some way? Some tips?

Comment: A stream is bad idea since you will by default always only have access to one element, you won't be able to compare two elements. Instead just write a normal `for` loop to implement your desired logic.

Comment: You also might want to consider how to handle edge cases. Eg. for triangles the logic of your code segment fails if the line segments are collinear (unless you deliberately want to count that as a triangle)

Comment: @collapsar why does it fails for triangles? Considering that i implement a for loop, i think i scroll the list with a nested for loop that goes through all the segments and if a segment has **endingPoint == startingPoint** of another segment and there is an index distance >= 2 then I can consider it a polygon

Comment: Imagine all line segments having the same orientation, ie. the two smaller ones lie 'on top' of the third one producing a 'triangle' with 0 area. Do you count this as a (degenerate) triangle? Or do you catch this case when the LinkedList is created ? (Note that this degeneracy can occur for all lengths > 2).

Comment: Notes (my opinion): no reason to check `isEmpty()`, already covered by `size() < 3` || no reason to cast `size()` to `long` || no reason to have one (different) test for `size() == 3` || regarding specification: is it really **enough** to have the end point of last segment being the same as start of first segment? and why not for n=3 (as written)?

Comment: @user16320675 u re right but it was isEmpty(), anyway i decided to implement **size() == 3** because it was the easiest way to check it, I wouldn't have wasted time doing cycles later if I already knew the size was 3

Comment: @collapsar this is a case that I haven't considered yet but that I should take into account, it shouldn't be calculated as a triangle, but I don't know how to handle it yet

Comment: I guess one way or another you'll have to check for the angles between each adjacent pair of edges, so you'd flag encountering 0 and PI (or maybe branch into more specialized checkers to avoid the pitfall of rounding errors). Do you expect your method to handle arbitrary LinkedList instances? If you don't there is the option of subclassing LinkedList and handle the issues during construction.

Comment: @collapsar thats what ive done: 'private boolean isAClosedArea(LinkedList<T> polygon) {
        if ((long) polygon.size() < 3) return false;

        if((long)polygon.size() > 3){
            for (int i = 0; i < polygon.size(); i++){
                for (int j = i+1; j < polygon.size(); j++){
                    if (polygon.get(i).p1().equals(polygon.get(j).p2()) && (j - i >= 2)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }'  now i have to check just for the case that we were talking about

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out above a stream is not really ideal here. You certainly can do it, but this seems easier:

```
private boolean isAClosedArea(LinkedList<Segment> polygon){
    if (polygon.size() < 3) return false;
    
    Point position = polygon.get(0).getFrom();

    for(Segment segment : polygon) {
        if (!position.equals(segment.getFrom())) {
            return false;
        }
        position = segment.getTo();
    }
    return position.equals(polygon.get(0).getFrom())
}
```

Also note there are no checks for intersections here! And maybe a whole lot more edge-cases that I am forgetting about...

Comment: but in this method i am not comparing only the first segment with the others? what I have done in these hours is:    `private boolean isAClosedArea(LinkedList<T> polygon) {
        if ((long) polygon.size() < 3) return false;

        if((long)polygon.size() > 3){
            for (int i = 0; i < polygon.size(); i++){
                for (int j = i+1; j < polygon.size(); j++){
                    if (polygon.get(i).p1().equals(polygon.get(j).p2()) && (j - i >= 2)){
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }`

Comment: no, you are checking for a continous line (is the to of the last segment equal to the from in the next?). in your code you are comparing only two segments (immediate return), you are unneccessarily using a double loop (which can work, its just very hard to understand. the i-j part simply breaks my head). if you can not understand my solution maybe get a paper and start simulating what you WANT to do, then transform it into code.

Comment: ok now I understand what you mean, but the problem remains, your method looks for a polygon that necessarily starts with the segment in polygon position 0, while there could be a polygon that is composed of **segment (position 6) + segment (position 7) + segment (position 8)**

Comment: ah, you mean you want to check if there is a subset contained in the list that can form a polygon? That was very much not clear to me from the original question. Your method name as well is very misleading... In that case push all positions encountered into a map, with the key being the point itself and the value the position of said position in the list. if you encounter a match check if there were at least 2 lines in between. sidenote: that is very much too complex to write correctly in one go now, i would add some test cases.